# React - update value in class based on variable outside of class

Tags: reactjs

I've a React class that renders a login form, diplaying a username, password and submit button.

When the form is submitted i make an async function call (external to the class) to AWS Auth which successfully returns and writes the response to the console.

I want to use the async response in the class - how do i go about this? As i say it is writing to the console, i just need this in the class.

I've tried reading the currentsession variable directly, however, it doesn't update.

```
import React from 'react';
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({ // config here})

let user;
let currentsession;

export async function signIn(username, password) {
  try {
      user = await Auth.signIn(username, password);
      console.log(user);
      currentsession = await Auth.currentSession();
      console.log(currentsession);
  } catch (error) {
      console.log('error signing in', error);
  }
}

class SignIn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }
  
  handleSubmit(event) {
    signIn(this.state.username, this.state.password);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text" name="username" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <label>
            String:
            <input type="text" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <div>{ currentsession }</div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default SignIn;
```

**UPDATE**

The reply i accepted worked perfectly and answered the question. It did also inspire another answer which i've included here, removing the external function.

I realised i could make the handleSubmit function async and handle it there. Code is:

```
  async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      let user = await Auth.signIn(this.state.username, this.state.password);
      this.setState( { response: 'Login Success!' });
    } catch(err) {
      this.setState( { response: err.message });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why is the signin function outside the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not keep variables outside of your components. Most probably, you want to keep this `user` and `currentSession` in your state. Since `signIn` function is `async` it returns a promise. Use it and update your state according to your return value.

I'm mimicking the API's here, don't mind the code. Just check the `signIn` function and how I return the values. You can change the logic according to your needs. Also, see the `handleSubmit` function to see how I update the state.

Since the code snippet doesn't support `async/await` (I guess) here is a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/playground-forked-up53k?file=/src/App.js).

```
function userApi() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve("foo"), 500));
}

function sessionApi() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve("session"), 500));
}

async function signIn(username, password) {
  try {
    const user = await userApi();
    const currentSession = await sessionApi();
    return { user, currentSession };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error signing in", error);
    return error;
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      user: null,
      currentSession: null
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { user, currentSession } = await signIn(
      this.state.username,
      this.state.password
    );
    this.setState({ user, currentSession });
  }

  render() {
    const { user, currentSession } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Name:
            <input
              type="text"
              name="username"
              value={this.state.username}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            String:
            <input
              type="text"
              name="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <div>
          {currentSession && user && (
            <span>
              {user}-{currentSession}
            </span>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```